# Why is an "apropos history" terminal window being launched from intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I typically use `command-shift-a` in Intellij to choose an `Action` to *run*.

[image]

But now it is bringing up an *`apropos history`* window that I have no idea what is about/what it means.

[image]

Why is this window being launched .. and .. *can I have my `Action|Run` back* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a *mac system wide* setting.

[image]

Not sure when this happened since I had been happily using command-shift-A for at least a couple of years and this is the first time the above behavior occurred afaicr.  I disabled them in the `Keyboard|Shortcuts` dialog:

[image]